# Is this example incorrect according to the given definition of the definition by recursion?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, recursion

Here is the theorem that defines definition by recursion in the book of Dirk van Dalen.
[image]

Then, the author gives an example.
[image]

From my point of view, this example is not transparent.
The reason is that for the case of $Sub(\phi_1\square\phi_2)$, we cannot explicitly use $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, and can only operate with $Sub(\phi_1)$ and $Sub(\phi_2)$.
It seems it would be correct to define it in this way, for example:
$$ 
Sub(\phi_1\square\phi_2) = Sub(\phi_1)\cup Sub(\phi_2)\cup\{\mathtt{argmax_{\psi_1\in Sub(\phi_1)}\mathtt{rank}(\psi_1)}\square\mathtt{argmax_{\psi_2\in Sub(\phi_2)}\mathtt{rank}(\psi_2)}\}
$$
We have the same problem defining $Sub(\neg\phi)$.

Am I right? If yes, then it is bizarre that the author hasn't emphasized that point. I wouldn't say it isn't worth stressing, especially for beginners.

Comment: In principle correct. You have to apply a slightly more general form of [Recursion Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Principle_of_Recursive_Definition#Strong_Version) where we have $f(n+1)=g(n, f(n))$ instead of simply $f(n+1)=g(f(n))$.

Comment: This means that e.g. $F (\lnot \varphi)=H_{\lnot}(F(\varphi), \varphi)$.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, so then $H_{\neg}\colon A\times PROP\to A$ and $H_{\square}\colon A^2\times PROP^2\to A$? May it then happen we need to define $H_{\neg}$ and $H_{\square}$ recursively themselves?